# Android Game Framework

Tags: android, frameworks

I'm a Flash developer looking to get into Android/iPhone game development.
Android is more important to me, because I don't have any iOS device to test on, and I don't really like apple either :P (could you blame a flash developer for that?)

What is a good game framework for developing android games? Multi-platform is always a huge bonus but not everything for me.

I've been looking at Rokon and it seems ok, but the tutorials/examples are a little sketchy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should also give [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) a shot.

Comment: For my next 2d game I was thinking of using AndEngine as well. They have a sample program on the Android Market so you can check out its capabilites on a phone. Looks pretty good.

Comment: Looked into AndEngine, seems like most straight forward platform. Thanks :)

Comment: looking at the cross platform concept cocos2d-x or emo game engine  is good right?

Comment: the problem with cocod2dx is that it lack documentation for android, and for a newbie to mobile game development it is really frustrating :)

Answer (score 3):

This [question on GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/89/are-there-any-2d-gaming-libraries-frameworks-engines-for-android) may provide some insight. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with Flash, you might want to look into [Adobe AIR for Android](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/air2/android/).

Comment: I was using the Beta for some time before it was released but I don't feel that it is a viable alternative just yet. The % of users that have android 2.2 is pretty small at the moment and many people would simply run away from the app once they find they have to have the 17mb AIR for Android file. This is unfortunate but I feel it is the truth

Answer (score 0):

Now cocos2dx is also great ,it is in c++ so it give the FPS also you can easily port to any other OS. It is also difficult to start, after learn it provide more promising then any other engine.
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/). Uses Java, documentation has gotten better, and quite a [few games](http://mobilegameengines.com/game_engines/32-libgdx) available for it.