# Android Gaming Frameworks

Tags: java, android, 2d-games

I was considering creating a 2D game, and was wondering if there are any good open source or potentially paid (if not too expensive) frameworks for developing games.

Anything out there already?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this previous discussion for some more options:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981781/android-game-framework

Answer (score 0):

AndEngine is for Android.
libgdx is desktop/android framework.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Unity, it's rather nice, though the terms are a bit expensive.

Comment: Unity is great for 3d games, but not really optimal for 2d games.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard good things about Corona.

http://www.anscamobile.com/

I have looked for a decent Android game framework and not been able to find many. The best I have found is the Cocos2D port for android but it is quite dated and you need to reference the IOS documents to learn how to use it and there is very little support.

Comment: Corona is pretty good. However the code is written in Lua and the compiler outputs to Android, among other targets.

Comment: this hits different in 2021

Answer (score 0):

If you want cocos2d for android the best solution is [WiEngine](http://www.wiyun.com/web/wiengine)